# How to get your hands on exception object caught by default ipython exception handler?

Tags: python, exception, ipython

Suppose I'm running some code interactively in IPython and it produces an uncaught exception, like:

```
In [2]: os.waitpid(1, os.WNOHANG)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-bacc7636b058> in <module>()
----> 1 os.waitpid(1, os.WNOHANG)

OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

This exception is now intercepted by the default IPython exception handler and produces an error message. Is it possible somehow to extract the exception object that was caught by IPython?

I want to have the same effect as in:

```
# Typing this into IPython prompt:
try:
    os.waitpid(1, os.WNOHANG)
except Exception, exc:
    pass
# (now I can interact with "exc" variable)
```

but I want it without this `try/except` boilerplate.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think `sys.last_value` should do the trick:

```
In [8]: 1/0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/ubuntu/<ipython console> in <module>()

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

In [11]: sys.last_value
Out[11]: ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',)
```

If you want even more fun with such things, checkout the [traceback module](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html), but that probably won't be of much use within ipython.